# URL cannot be found on the server for my FuelPHP Module

Tags: php, module, routes, fuelphp

I'm creating a small FuelPHP application that contains a blog module. In this module the posts controller just assigns a simple view to the template for the posts index.

I have read through the FuelPHP docs and have the following settings in the app config for the modules:

```
'module_paths' => array(
    APPPATH.'modules'.DS,
    APPPATH.'..'.DS.'globalmods'.DS
),

'always_load' => array(
    'packages' => array(
        'auth',
        'orm',
    ),
    'modules' => array(
        'admin',
        'blog',
    ),
),
```

The application itself is outside my WAMP www docroot but the assets, htaccess and index.php are inside.

I have no idea why the server cannot find the localhost/blog/posts/index URL as I have followed everything advised on the docs and the homepage (*root* route) seems to display fine. It is only when I click the blog link (blog/posts/index) that it states

"Not Found

The requested URL /blog/posts/index was not found on this server."

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is that error by your webserver of by fuel?

Comment: It looks like the webserver but I have no idea why. I'm wondering if it's to do with the paths in the index.php file and the structure of my application.

Comment: If it is the webserver, this is likely because of webserver-configuration. Depending on your webserver, those are called rewrite rules or URL rewriting or similar.

Comment: If that's the case, how come the root homepage works?

Comment: Because normally the root pages are resolved via the [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html) directive which is only working for directory indexes. Your root page directory index highly likely is called `index.php` and your webserver is configured to pick `index.php` if one exists.

Comment: Just to be sure. Have you made sure normal routing works?

Comment: You don't need to load the module to be able to route to it, it will be loaded automatically. The standard .htaccess should work fine on a stock WAMP install, are you sure rewriting is enabled? What happens if you access http://localhost/index.php?blog/posts/index ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem myself.  Two key things I did were:

1) Start with a fresh copy of Fuel.  I was missing some sort of configuration file, so I create a brand new Fuel framework, and then added all the app files back in

2) Enabling the 'rewrite_module' in the Apache Modules (in the Wampserver config)

Try these two things and see what you get.